# cross site script not working in php form

Tags: php, html, forms

i have a form in one of my web pages where i have given an action php page with following html syntax.

```
<form name="form" action="test.php" method="get">
```

i have modified this to

```
<form name="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars('test.php') ?>" method="get">
```

but still when i type the following url in address bar

```
http://www.example.com/test.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E
```

it outputs in browser

```
http://www.example.com/test.php/"><script>alert('hacked')</script>
```

which is wrong.I want to secure my page for cross site scripting.please guide me where i m doing wrong.

Comment: You have a complete misunderstanding of what cross-site scripting is and how it works. There's no reason to do `htmlspecialchars('test.php')`.

Comment: To prevent XSS you need to validate inputs from the URL. If your page is static and you don't accept variables from then you don't have anything to validate. What you are doing in your php code has nothing to do with entering `http://www.example.com/test.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('hacked')%3C/script%3E` into the browser address bar. The browser and the server are separate entities and the browser will interpret what it will.

Comment: `action=""` - there.

Answer (score 0):

Never put user input directly into a page. You always want to sanitize it first.

The preferred method is whitelisting user input, which means checking valid attributes instead of invalid ones.

The safest thing to do is reject all input that does not satisfy your whitelist instead of trying to convert it to something valid.

See OWASP's site for more information. [Here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet) is their guideline to whitelisting input.